# How to print directly from Android?

Tags: java, android, printing, android-4.4-kitkat, android-print-framework

I have code to print a text file using Java, as seen below.

This program works fine in Java,  but I want to be able to use this code in Android,  or, if that is not possible, please can anyone help me solve this issue? I need to print a text file using Android, but I don't want to use cloud printing, but rather directly from my program.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobAdapter;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;

public class Print {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;

        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        /* locate a print service that can handle it */

        PrintService[] pservices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);

        /* create a print job for the chosen service */

        int printnbr = 0;
        DocPrintJob pj = pservices[printnbr].createPrintJob();

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\151_Proteam.key");
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);
            PrintJobWatcher pjDone = new PrintJobWatcher(pj);
            /* print the doc as specified */
            pj.print(doc, aset);

        }
        catch (Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is Print Job Watcher class.

```
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobAdapter;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;


public class PrintJobWatcher {

        // true iff it is safe to close the print job's input stream
        private boolean done = false;


        public PrintJobWatcher(DocPrintJob job) {
                // Add a listener to the print job
                job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
                        public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                                allDone();
                        }

                        public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                                allDone();
                        }

                        public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                                allDone();
                        }

                        public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                                allDone();
                        }

                        void allDone() {
                                synchronized (PrintJobWatcher.this) {
                                        done = true;
                                        PrintJobWatcher.this.notify();
                                }
                        }
                });
        }

        public synchronized void waitForDone() {
                try {
                        System.out.println("Checking Printer Status...");
                        while (!done) {
                                /*System.out.println(FileUtils.getCurrentTimeForUseInAFileName()
                                                + " Waiting for the Print Job to Complete...");*/
                                wait();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Print Job Completed.");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a direct way to print using Android.

I have used http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/ this Serial Port API for Android to print using a USB-Serial port on a printer with Serial port.

Otherwise you will need a network printer and implement a driver+web interface for it in your app. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create your one printService since the version of Android 4.4.

Take a look at this blog http://visible-true.blogspot.com/2013/11/android-44-printing-framework_17.html (translate the page with chrome)

This is the link to the soure files in github https://github.com/sys1yagi/DropboxPrintService